# How to position :before & :after pseudo-elements on top of each other?

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

What's the best way to position one pseudo-element directly on top of another pseudo-element?

Let's say I want to make a fancy "checkbox" appear next to label here:

```css
label:before {
  content: "\00a0";
  color: #FFF;
  height: 6px;
  width: 6px;
  display: inline-block;
}

label:after {
  content: "\00a0";
  height: 18px;
  width: 18px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #ebd196;
  background-image: linear-gradient(top, #ebd196 4%, #e2b65d 5%, #ab8844 100%);
}
```

```html
<input id="pretty"><label for="pretty">Label text</label>
```

What is the stacking order of the pseudo-elements? Does :before appear below or above :after- which is better suited to be the border, and which the fill?

And what is the best positioning to apply to label, label:before & label:after to get the proper positioning?

Answer (score 41):

`:before` (or `::before`) is treated as the first child of the element it is being applied to, whilst `:after` (or `::after`) is treated as the last child. Therefore, `:after` would naturally cover `:before`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after

I imagine the best way to make sure they line up would be to use `position: relative;` on `label` and `position: absolute;` on the pseudo-elements along with the same values for `top`, `bottom` etc.

If you wanted to make a gradient border using pseudo-elements then you could do something like this:

```
label {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 2px;
    margin: 2px;
}

label:before {
    content:"";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: white;
}

label:after {
    content:"";
    position: absolute;
    top: -2px;
    bottom: -2px;
    left: -2px;
    right: -2px;
    z-index: -2;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #1e5799 13%, #efe22f 79%);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QqzJg/

You might find this useful:

http://css-tricks.com/examples/GradientBorder/

Answer (score 2):

Rather than position, add "vertical-align: middle" to :after and :before.

```
label {}
label::before{vertical-align: middle;}
label::after {vertical-align: middle;}
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
body {
    background-color: #333;
}

.cloud {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 400px;
    height: 130px;
    background: linear-gradient(white, skyblue);
    margin-top: 200px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: auto;
}

.cloud::before {
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    width: 180px;
    height: 180px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    top: -82px;
    left: 160px;
    z-index: -1;
}

.cloud::after {
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    width: 180px;
    height: 180px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    top: -83px;
    left: 50px;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="cloud"></div>
```